# Calculate Displacement when velocity is a function of displacement

Tags: integration, physics

Particle is moving on a straight line and where velocity varies with its displacement as $v=\sqrt{4+4s}$. Find displacement at *t = 2* s if *s=0* at *t=0*. I am not able to figure out how to approach this.

PS. I don't know methods like Integration by parts as I am in class XI

Comment: Can you write the differential equation of the movement?

Comment: I have posted everything given in the question.

Comment: $v = \frac{ds}{dt} $.

 You will get the differential equation as Yves told you that.

$\frac{ds}{dt} = \sqrt{4+4s}$.

 Boundary condition has been given to you.

Comment: I know ds=vdt but I am not able to integrate it

Comment: Rewrite the differential equation so that $s$ and $t$ are on either side of the equality and integrate.

Comment: Yes Yes I did this ds/v=dt but the problem is in integrating it. Maybe you can show me how to do so.

Comment: Eliminate the variable $v$.

Comment: What exactly I need to do ?

Comment: Eliminate $v$ means: from what you have, write an equation where the variable $v$ does not appear.

Comment: LOL I have shifted substituted everything but how to I integrate ??/

Comment: You still haven't shown what you have to integrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have been told in the various comments and answer the diffrential equation is $$\frac{ds}{dt} = \sqrt{4+4s}$$ This equation is separable if you rewrite it as $$\frac{dt}{ds} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{4+4s}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s}}=\frac{1}{2}(1+s)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$ I suppose that you recognize that the rhs is just the derivative of $(1+s)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. So, you have $$dt=\frac{1}{2}(1+s)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=(\sqrt{1+s})'$$ Integrating both sides then gives $$t+c=\sqrt{1+s}
$$ and you know this initial condition ($s=0$ if $t=0$), which can only happen if $c=1$.

Squaring now both sides then gives you $$1+s=(t+1)^2$$ that is to say $$s=2t+t^2$$

I hope and wish this becomes clearer to you. I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: You are very welcome. Since you don't know yet techniques for integration, you could have suspected something simple. Just remember the trick; you will use it quite often as soon as they will start teaching you differential equations. Cheers :)

Comment: Sir, I am quite new to this and I am not able to make out how did t+c came and how c is equal to 1.

Comment: I shall add more details to my naswer by now.

Comment: Is this better ?

Comment: No. $c$ is the integration constant since whatever $c$ could be, the derivative of $t+c$ is always $1$.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy just keep on substituting the given relation of 'v' and 's' in 3 general equation and you will get displacement=8m.

Comment: Can you please show me how you got this? nd you mean the Kinematics formula ?

Comment: Yes, in v=u+at put v^2=4+4s .. then put t=0 and s=0.. you get u=2 . Now use s=ut+1/2*a*t^2 with t=2s and similarly find v in terms of a . Then put both of them in the given v and s equation . You get 'a' and then displacement.

Answer (score 0):

$v=u+at$

Putting the value of v from the given equation($v^2=4+4s$) in this and substituting $t=0$ and $s=0$,we get
$v^2=4$

Thus $v=2=u$
(negative is not possible since initial velocity is positive thus displacement could never be negative).

Putting in $v^2=u^2+2as$,we get

$4+4s=4+2as$

$4s=2as$

Thus,$a=2$

Putting these obtained values in $s=ut+(1/2)at^2$ and $t=2$,

$s=2(2)+(1/2)(2)(4)$

$ =4+4$

$  =8$

Thus we get the required displacement along with other variables like acceleration(it'll help to find these variables if it is like a paragraph based question or something like that)
Hope you like the answer

Comment: This really helps if u have problems with differential equations.i was too a bit confused with differentiation but if you get it right,youre gonna save a lot of time